# failed to install weidner/goutte composer package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

> I'm using Laravel Framework 7.30.4 and PHP 7.4.23

> How to install weidner/goutte it's throwing below error. please help

```
Using version ^2.1 for weidner/goutte
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update weidner/goutte
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires weidner/goutte ^2.1 -> satisfiable by weidner/goutte[2.1.0].
    - weidner/goutte 2.1.0 requires illuminate/support ^8 -> found illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: Version constraint? https://github.com/dweidner/laravel-goutte#version-constraint You should be using 1.6 for Laravel 7. Try with that version and if that fails, please update your question with the new error message.

Comment: Can you post your composer.json for us?

Comment: yes, please have [look](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b129Y6ncBYQDUHtSFam2kHkD6-gZA6jQ/view?usp=sharing) this link `composer.json`